# How can I fix value error on for-loop in python array?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

For a homework assignment we were asked to generate the specific array below and find the count of the even numbers in the array using a for loop. I'm running into a value error after running my for loop.

```
Q2 = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size = (10, 10))
print("The list of numbers in Q2 array = ", Q2)

even_count = 0
odd_count = 0            

for i in range(len(Q2)):
    if(Q2[i] % 2 == 0):
        even_count = even_count + 1
    else:
        odd_count = odd_count + 1

print("The count of the even numbers in Q2 array = ", even_count)
```

I'm getting the following message when I run the for loop: *ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*

I've searched for an answer for this problem and have found all kinds of explanation of the value error and Booleans, but none of them helped specific with my type of code. Or didn't elaborate enough for someone who is very new to Python to understand (me!) Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Since you printed the array `Q2`, you should easily see that it is a 2D array. A 10x10 array to be accurate. That is what `size` parameter means. So `Q2[i]` is not a number. It is a 1D array (and 2D array is an array of 1D array). You can compute `Q2[i]%2` still, because of numpy's vectorization: it returns a 1D-array of all `Q2[i][?]%2`. So it is a 1D-array, size 10, of number 0 or 1. You can even compare that to 0 with `Q2[i]%2==0`, still, because `==` will be applied by numpy of all those 10 1 or 0. So you get a size 10 array of booleans. But then, you can use that as an argument for `if`

Comment: Hence the error. You have to decide how to transform that array of boolean into a single one if you want to use it as an argument to `if`. Hence the message with `.any` or `.all`. If I weren't pretty sure that you just missed the fact that `Q2` is a 2d array, I would advise you do use neither of `any` or `all`, nor `if`. And to simply add `sum(Q2[i]%2==0)` to `even_count` and `sum(Q2[i]%2==0)` to odd_count. And then, why not, even remove to outer `for loop`, and just replace your whole code by `even_count=(Q2%2==0).sum()` and `odd_count=(Q2%2==1).sum()`.

Comment: But since I am sure that you just missed the fact that `Q2` is a 2D array, I won't post such an answer, and instead, remind you that `Q2` is a 2D array :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q2 is an array of array so you need another `for` loop.

```
import numpy as np


Q2 = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size = (10, 10))
print("The list of numbers in Q2 array = ", Q2)

even_count = 0
odd_count = 0            

for i in Q2:
    for j in i:
      if (j % 2 == 0):
        even_count = even_count + 1
      else:
        odd_count = odd_count + 1

print("The count of the even numbers in Q2 array = ", even_count)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This was exactly what I was looking for.

I'm very new to python and we just learned about the types of arrays this week in our class and the professor expects to do a lot of our own research ont the assignments.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a two-dimensional array (10 x 10). So `Q2[i]` is still a (one-dimensional) array, not a single integer as you seem to expect. Hence the error, because in your subarray you may have both even and odd numbers - in other words the truth value of your check is ambiguous, as the error message says.

Male two loops, or simply create a one-dimension array